# How do I import a type definition module? (error TS2656: ...not a module)

Tags: typescript

I have a simple npm module, [emitter20](https://github.com/raineorshine/emitter20), that I am trying to add type definitions to. Here is all 20 lines of its source:

```
module.exports = function() {
  var subscribers = []
  return {
    on: function (eventName, cb) {
      subscribers.push({
        eventName: eventName,
        cb: cb
      })
    },
    trigger: function (eventName, data) {
      subscribers
        .filter(function (subscriber) {
          return subscriber.eventName === eventName
        })
        .forEach(function (subscriber) {
          subscriber.cb(data)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the `index.d.ts` file in the emitter20 project root:

```
declare module 'emitter20' {
  interface IEmitter {
    on: (eventName: string, cb: (data?: any) => void) => void;
    trigger: (eventName: string, data?: any) => void;
  }
  interface EmitterFactory {
    new(): IEmitter;
  }
  export = IEmitter;
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
declare module 'emitter20' {
  export interface IEmitter {
    on: (eventName: string, cb: (data?: any) => void) => void;
    trigger: (eventName: string, data?: any) => void;
  }
  export interface EmitterFactory {
    new(): IEmitter;
  }
}
```

I try to import it into my project like this:

```
import IEmitter = require('emitter20')

export interface SwapManager extends IEmitter {
  manager: any;
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
error TS2656: Exported external package typings file './node_modules/emitter20/index.d.ts' is not a module. Please contact the package author to update the package definition.
```

**How do I define and import the type definition for the `emitter20` module?**

*(Aside: Typescript imports/exports... one hell of a learning curve!)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that this is not a "proper" JS module and be warned that it doesn't actually expose any types per se, so you will not be able to subclass it... I think.

If this was a "normal"(?) or ES6 JS module which returned classes, etc you would be able to just simply use a bunch of `export this; export that; export default function factory()` like you tried, but this is one of those modules that are a function and `export =` is used in my approach which is documented as:

> For backwards compatibility with CommonJS and AMD style modules,
>   TypeScript also supports export-equals declarations of the form export
>   = Point. Unlike default export declarations, which are just shorthand for an export named default, export-equals declarations designate an
>   entity to be exported in place of the actual module.

I know of the following two approaches to get this "typed":

### Approach 1: Use an Interface:

Pros:

- Gives you intellisense/autocomplete and type safety

Cons:

- Doesn't expose the interface for explicit type declarations (you can't declare a variable with that type)

**main.ts**

```
import * as emitterFactory from 'emitter20';

var emitterInstance = emitterFactory();
emitterInstance.on(...)
```

**types.d.ts**

```
declare module 'emitter20' {
    interface IEmitter {
        on: (eventName: string, cb: (data?: any) => void) => void;
        trigger: (eventName: string, data?: any) => void;
    }

    interface IEmitterFactory {
        (): IEmitter;
    }

    var EmitterFactory : IEmitterFactory;

    export = EmitterFactory;
}
```

### Approach 2: Function + Namespace with the same name

Pros:

- Gives you intellisense/autocomplete and type safety
- Exposes the interface

Cons:

- Looks a bit like dark magic? :)

**main.ts**

```
import * as emitter from 'emitter20';

var emitterInstance : emitter.IEmitter = emitter();
emitterInstance.on("event", (data : any) => {
    console.log(data.foo);
})
emitterInstance.trigger("event", {"foo": "bar"});
```

**Output:**

```
bar
```

**types.d.ts**

```
declare module 'emitter20' {

    function Emitter(): Emitter.IEmitter;
    namespace Emitter {
        interface IEmitter {
            on: (eventName: string, cb: (data?: any) => void) => void;
            trigger: (eventName: string, data?: any) => void;
        }
    }


    export = Emitter;
}
```

### Approach 3: Declare a global namespace

Pros:

- Gives you intellisense/autocomplete and type safety
- Exposes the interface
- Doesn't look like dark magic

Cons:

- The `Emitter` namespace becomes global and visible everywhere (global ambient declaration)

**main.ts**

```
import * as emitter from 'emitter20';

var emitterInstance : Emitter.IEmitter = emitter();
```

**types.d.ts**

```
declare namespace Emitter
{
    export interface IEmitter {
        on: (eventName: string, cb: (data?: any) => void) => void;
        trigger: (eventName: string, data?: any) => void;
    }

    export interface IEmitterFactory {
        (): Emitter.IEmitter;
    }
}

declare module 'emitter20' {
    var EmitterFactory : Emitter.IEmitterFactory;

    export = EmitterFactory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I copied the code exactly for Approach 2 and I still got the "not a module" error :/.

Comment: @Raine Both work for me, including running the code.  I have also previously used Approach 2 for typings for another module. Make sure the `d.ts` file is not excluded (or if you use explicit file list - make sure it's included in your `tsconfig.json`. I have added an example with out put to the question. Please consider marking the answer as accepted

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: latest stable 1.8.x

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I'm glad it is working for you, as it means I must still be missing something! I tried isolating it down to the smallest possible reproducible state in this gist: https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/33390aec8abc0ee403ee12c2caff4d89. I am either getting a "module not found" or "emitter20 is not a module" error no matter what I do.

Comment: @Raine The `d.ts` file must be included during compilation like a normal code file: `tsc main.ts emitter20.d.ts` or alternatively you can use a `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: @Raine I commented on your gist with a bit more detail, because I can't format comments here and add code, etc,

Comment: Steps to reproduce added to gist.

Comment: @Raine Here is a full code sample: https://github.com/ivanz/emitter20-typescript-types-sample